atmega32u4 connect PC
I made a custom PCB with C-type USB and atmega32u4 (arduino leonardo). But my PC doesn't recognize the atmega32u4.
Here are my schematic.
Why my PC doesn't recognize the pcb in schematic?

What code did you put on the chip?

Have you bootloaded the microcontroller?

This answer lists some potential issues with your design. It is not exhausting.
Software prerequisites
An ATmega32u4 without a program that sets up the USB module will not respond to any USB request from a USB host like a PC. Therefore the PC will not "see" it.
You need to flash a working program, for example a boot loader.
Hardware prerequisites
The ATmega32u4 needs a working clock. You connected the crystal mainly correctly. But its capacitors need to be between CRYSTAL1 and GND, and CRYSTAL2 and GND, respectively.

There should be preflashed factory DFU bootloader. What I wonder about more is how weirdly is the crystal connected...

@KIIV Thanks for pointing out the hardware issue. -- Concerning the preflashed bootloader, does Microchip deliver its MCUs always preflashed? I would not expect this.

AFAIK only for USB capable chips, everything else is blank. At least that was a case few years ago (but in previous work I just created shield for RPi with push button, dual ISP and it just flashed 16u2 and mega2560 and then used usb to upload final FW :D).

Whether or not the ATmegaXu4 comes from the factory with a bootloader (and which clock option fusing) depends on the exact ordering code. The -MU (QFN) parts like the one shown in the schematic are shipped without a bootloader.
